# Remove icon space - Button Item DotNetBar

Tags: winforms, dotnetbar

Is this possible to remove or hide icon space from SubItems collection ?

[Icon space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r11Xh.png)

Comment: yeah it probably is

Comment: Yepp, just set `ShowImageMargin` to `false`

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko Thanks, but there is no "ShowImageMargin" parameter for DotNetBar.ButtonItem